# How to limit orders to cart in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I want to limit customers to buy only three products, and the total quantity should be three only. 
**Conditions:**

*1st condition:*

```
product1-> 1
product2-> 1
product3-> 1
```

total qty is 3 here.

*2nd condition:*

```
product1-> 2
product3->1
```

total qty is 3 here.

*3rd condition:*

```
product1-> 3
```

total qty is 3 here.

How to limit cart section like this in opencart ?

Comment: does this looks suitable? http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=443

Comment: i can set your product limit using vqmode when max limit product checkout button hide on your page and display message so this process  right for you?

Comment: thanks, this idea from your questions before month have any suggestion for changes please suggest me.

Comment: @ravipatel. Sure I ll check. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Parin Order Quantity Limit for minimum and maximum order limit on cart](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17008)

1. You can manage limit orders to cart from admin panel.
2. if your limit greater product on cart not checkout the order.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your extension Ravi :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for the code changes that do this?

If so, then I would advise coding in catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php early in the add() function

```
$cart_products = $this->cart->getProducts();
$cart_quantity = 0;
foreach ($cart_products as $cart_product)
    $cart_quantity += $cart_product['quantity'];

if (($cart_quantity + (int)$this->request->post['quantity']) > 3)
    $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_cart_full');
```

That code isn't tested by the way, and obviously I've hard-coded the 3. Also  you may have to put something in the tpl of the page you're adding from to actually display the error.